# Cannot interact with dropdown in Chrome

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Beginning python users here. I want to select an option from a dropdown list. I keep getting "Element not interactable." I don't believe there is any type of label overlay on the dropdown, and I am manually able to click on the dropdown without problems. I've tried a number of things, as shown commented, with the associated error below.

Here is my code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
#from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import action_chains
#from selenium.webdriver.common.actions import Actions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
#from selenium.webdriver.remote import Remote
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions



service = Service()

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://gtc.clubautomation.com/")

#
#
# removed code to login and move to reservations page
#
#


reserve_court_link = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="menu_reserve_a_court")
reserve_court_link.click()

driver.maximize_window()
driver.refresh()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,600)")


#Choose service (unecessary manually, but hopefully driving further options?? Only one option to pick)
service_dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//select[@id='component'][@name='component']"))
service_dropdown.select_by_value("2")

#Choose pickleball option
pickleball_dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//select[@id='location'][@name='location']"))
dropdown_element = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//select[@id='location'][@name='location']")

#Verify dropdown exists
if pickleball_dropdown is not None: 
    print("drop down exists")
else:
    print("dropdown does NOT exist")

#Verify I have the right dropdown
test_option = pickleball_dropdown.first_selected_option
print(test_option.get_attribute("innerHTML"))

#print values of dropdown
for opt in pickleball_dropdown.options:
    print("option: " + opt.get_attribute("innerHTML") + " : " + opt.get_attribute("value"))


#select by visible text doesn't seem to do anything.
pickleball_dropdown.select_by_visible_text("All Service Locations")


# expand housing type dropdown using javascript -- doesn't seem to actually expand dropdown
dropdown_trigger = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//select[@id='location'][@name='location']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", dropdown_trigger)

#Wait for object to be clickable -- times out.
#WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='location'][@name='location']"))).click()

#error: ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
dropdown_element.click()

#AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'click'
#pickleball_dropdown.click()

#ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
pickleball_dropdown.select_by_value("35")
```

I've included screen snaps of the page I want to interact with, and the HTML

```html
<div class="reserve-court-new-header">Make a New Reservation</div>
<div class="reserve-court-new">
<div class="ca-element-error-wrapper">
     <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="37688" id="user_id">
</div>    
<div class="ca-element-error-wrapper">
     <input type="hidden" name="event_member_token_reserve_court" value="b3f10b9d113922226d18db05b8c3a448" id="event_member_token_reserve_court">
</div>    
<div class="ca-element-error-wrapper">
     <input type="hidden" name="current_guest_count" value="0" id="current_guest_count">
</div>    
<div class="r-line">
     <div class="t-block">What Service?</div>
     <div class="i-block"><div class="ca-element-error-wrapper">
          <span class="ca-pro-ui"><span class="select-input-container">
               <select name="component" id="component" class="ca-select">
                   <option value="2" selected="selected">Tennis</option>
             </select>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                    (function($) {
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            $("#component").caSelect({"width":150,"tickWidth":30,"selectType":"select"});
                        });
                    })(jQuery)
              </script>
       </span>
   </span>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="clear-both"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="r-line" >
      <div class="t-block">Where?</div>
      <div class="i-block"  style="display: none;">
           <div class="ca-element-error-wrapper">
                <span class="ca-pro-ui"><span class="select-input-container">
                     <select name="club" id="club" class="ca-select">
                         <option value="-1" selected="selected">All Locations</option>
                         <option value="1">Lifetime Tennis GTC</option>
                    </select>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    (function($) {
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            $("#club").caSelect({"width":150,"tickWidth":30,"selectType":"select"});
                        });
                    })(jQuery)
                </script>
            </span>
       </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="i-block"><div class="ca-element-error-wrapper">
     <span class="ca-pro-ui"><span class="select-input-container">
          <select name="location" id="location" class="ca-select">
              <option value="-1">All Service Locations</option>
              <option value="1">Tennis</option>
              <option value="35">Pickleball / Mini Tennis</option>
          </select>
```

[image: Master screen]

[image: First dropdown -- as far as I know, unnecessary to click for the ensuing dropdowns, but added jic]

[image: Dropdown I cannot click on!! Give me pickleball!]

Comment: You have three unclosed `<div>` elements

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think that would be the issue? The web page source is very long, so I only included the part I think is relevant. I didn't write this web page, but it is definitely functional. Thousands of people use it every day.

Comment: If that's the case, you have more problems than you could shake a stick at. And trying to solve issues are chasing a ghost. Validate your HTML and see how many other errors you might have.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The full HTML is valid. As I said, it's a public facing webpage that I didn't write. Since it's so long, I just included the part that renders the dropdowns. I'm able to interact with other parts of the page via selenium  - pressing buttons, clicking links, selecting radio buttons. The only part that isn't working as I expected is this specific dropdown.

Comment: It can't be valid if you are missing closing tags (though there are exceptions to that).

Comment: Sorry if I am not being clear. I copied a section of a valid, and very long page source into my question, primarily to indicate that I've picked the dropdowns I intended and the options I intended. That section of code is very small. I included some extra lines preceding the SELECT html in case I'm missing something obvious, like a parent label or js generating the options.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using selenium for a while, In most cases I rarely use Select, I think it is not very Not sure. I omitted some of the code. I hope you can understand it. So My experience is as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

> ```
> driver = Chrome()
> ```

1. Click this option to make the drop-down box appear, Thinking with this drop-down box as a table with multiple rows and columns.
2. Ready to traverse this table row by row, like this

> ```
> rows = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(ec.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)
> ```

The above code xpath is each row of this drop-down box, so it returns a List[WebElement]

3. Now we need to traverse the table, and if this element meets your criteria, please use it. Here is an example of choosing a gender.

> ```
> for row in rows:
>     temp = row.find_element(By.XPATH,'.//option')
>     if 'male' in temp.text:
>        temp.click()
>        break
> ...
> ```

in selenium 4.11 .......

Comment: Thanks for this answer! The rows object gets populated, but it doesn't seem to find any options from './/option'. My approach with the Select object and Options method does return the text of the three visible options. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: @Quicksilver, I think that is nor real Select, I have been using selenium for a long time, Select is rarely used because it is unstable. I no idea with you said that but it doesn't seem to find any options from './/option'. Here xpath Write by doing what you want to do,  Based on the above, my simple guess is `eles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//select [@id="club"]/option')` ,then Evaluate attribute values one by one for selection: `for ele in eles: if ele.get_attribute('value')=='1': ele.click()`, Before these operations, first ensure that the drop-down box appears.